# Configuring nginx on Ubuntu on Digital Ocean servers (not as root user)

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I have installed nginx on Ubuntu 14.04 on my digital.

The installation was done not as root user but rather as non-root user with sudo privileges.

Installation instructions followed were:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

After isntallation, I have now set out to configure it. The nginx.config file was found in

```
/etc/nginx/
```

Apparently, when I open this file (it opens as read-only).
I know I can change permissions on this file using chown command.. but that doesn't seem right..

What's the right course of action here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify it with:

```
sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

The Nginx master process will likely execute as root in your setup (otherwise it won't be able to bind to port `80`), so it's fine to keep it as:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 root root .....
```